# How is pressure at the surface of horizontally accelerated fluid equal to atmospheric pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]
In the situation given in picture , How is pressure at surface of container equal to atmospheric pressure , since the container is accelerating forward therefore the surface is also accelerating forward, so the surface has some net force along horizontal to accelerate it and if it has net force along horizontal then that net force would also provide some pressure and hence the pressure>atmospheric pressure

Where am I going wrong can someone explain

Ps: I know that the surface will tilt but how will the horizontal force be affected by it?

Comment: If you accelerate the container, the fluid inside would have a tilted surface.

Comment: @mmesser314 I know that, but how will that affect it?